# How can I use socket.io to emit data to client-side whenever a variable change its values in server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

**Background**

I am using `rpio` to work with my `raspberry` as a server for my applications, and at the same time I want to be able to control GPIO using `javascript`. So far so good, I am a begginer and I am just trying to display info related to the GPIO on the html page.

**What I want to do**

I want to change some content dinamically at the cliend-side according to a variable that happens to be operated on the server-side; In other words, I want that whenever this variable change its values in server-side, `socket.io` sends it to client-side so I can work with (display) the updated version of that variable inside of a `paragraph` tag.
In my case, I just want to display on the page if a certain raspberry pin is high or low. I use a `blinkLed` function that has a `for` loop where a certain pin is turnet on and off at each iteration.
**Code**

I am rendering a home page '/', where I can click a button to send a post request to '/' and then it renders the blinkLed page, where is located the client-side part of `socketio` and where I want to display the pin state, inside of a paragraph; when such page loads, socketio executes the function `blinkLed()` on the server-side to do the `rpio` trick putting pins at high or low state through the `rpiowrite` functions. This is working fine. 
Notice that inside the function `blinkLed()` I am using `socket.emit` to emit a  string "high" or "low" everytime when `rpiowrite` is called inside of the `for` loop.

***app.js***

```
var rpio = require('rpio')
var app = require('express')()
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

async function blinkLed(socket){
rpio.open(12, rpio.OUTPUT, rpio.LOW);
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        /* On for 1 second */
        await rpio.write(12, rpio.HIGH);
        await rpio.sleep(1);
        await socket.emit('data','high')

        /* Off for half a second (500ms) */
        await rpio.write(12, rpio.LOW);
        await rpio.msleep(500);
        await socket.emit('data','low')

        }
}

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render('home')
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Blink Led Page');
    blinkLed(socket)
});

app.post("/", async function(req,res){
     res.render('blinkLed');
})

http.listen(3000,'0.0.0.0',function(){
    console.log('server on')
})
```

***blinkLed.ejs***

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

        function showParagraph(data){
                return document.getElementById('p').innerHTML=data
        }
        var socket = io();
           socket.on('data', function(data){
               showParagraph(data)
        })
        </script>
<h1>BlinkLed</h1>

<p id='p'></p>
<a href='/'>Back</a>
```

**The problem**

The `rpio` functions are working well; The problem is that, instead of showing the paragraph since the beggining of the for loop iteration, it only shows something after the end of the `for` iteration. It looks like `socketio` is just emmiting to the client-side only after the last iteration, then changing the value of the paragraph only after the last loop in the iteration had ended. I would like to listen to the changes at every iteration of the for loop. There is anyway to do it?

**Thank you in advance for any possible help!**

EDIT:improved question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rpio.write()` and `rpio.sleep()` and `socket.emit()` functions do not return a promise.  Therefore using `await` with them does nothing useful at all as `await` only does something useful when your awaiting a promise.

Therefore, your `for` loop is just a synchronous `for` loop and `socket.emit()` probably can't actually send its data until you give nodejs some cycles to process it which happens after the `for` loop is done.

It is also possible that the `socket.emit()` is actually sending the data, but the data arrives in such rapid fire on the client that you never get a chance to see a screen update and all you see is the final update.

The `rpio.sleep()` function blocks the node.js Javascript thread.  As it says right in [the doc for your  rpio libirary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpio): *"The sleep functions block, but rarely in these simple programs does one care about that.  Use a setInterval()/setTimeout() loop instead
if it matters".*  Well, here it does matter.

So, one solution here is to use an actual non-blocking delay that gives everyone a chance to actually process things:

```
// utility function that returns a promise that resolves after a delay
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}


for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    /* On for 1 second */
    rpio.write(12, rpio.HIGH);
    socket.emit('data','high')
    await delay(1000);

    /* Off for half a second (500ms) */
    rpio.write(12, rpio.LOW);
    socket.emit('data','low')
    await delay(500);
}
```